# Svg masking doesn't render when generated

Tags: svg, elm, image-masking, virtual-dom

```
<svg x="0" y="0" height="2048" width="4096" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; pointer-events: none;">
   <defs>
      <mask x="0" y="0" id="shadowLayerMask">
         <polygon fill="#FFF" points="1042,1578 630,2048 3902,2048 3370,1464"></polygon>
      </mask>
   </defs>
   <rect x="0" y="0" fill="red" mask="url(#shadowLayerMask)" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="2048" width="4096"></rect>
</svg>
```

Simple right? Here's the thing, if I drop this svg into an html file, the masking works perfectly. But when I generate the same svg with virtual dom, the mask has no effect and we just have a huge red rect.

Annoyingly I can get it to display when generated, if I open the developer tools and add a pointless `<defs></defs>` to the svg. That seems to kick the svg somehow and remind it that it needs to mask.

Anyone know what is going on here? Is there a workaround that doesn't involve setting a timer to inject an empty `defs`?

### Update:

here is the source

```
render : Layer -> Html
render { key, shader, mask, size } =
  let
    key' =
      key ++ "LayerMask"

    style' =
      [ "position" => "absolute"
      , "top" => "0px"
      , "left" => "0px"
      , "pointer-events" => "none"
      ]

    hw =
      [ A.height << toString <| getY size
      , A.width << toString <| getX size
      ]

    polygon =
      Svg.polygon
        [ A.fill "#FFF"
        , toPoints mask
        ]
        []

    mask' =
      node
        "mask"
        [ A.x "0", A.y "0", id key' ]
        [ polygon ]

    image =
      Svg.rect
        (A.x "0"
          ::
            A.y "0"
          --   :: A.xlinkHref shader
          ::
            A.fill "red"
          ::
            A.mask (url key')
          ::
            A.maskContentUnits "userSpaceOnUse"
          ::
            hw
        )
        []
  in
    Svg.svg
      (A.x "0" :: A.y "0" :: style style' :: hw)
      [ Svg.defs [] [ mask' ]
      , image
      ]
```

here are some relevant imports

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Svg
import Svg.Attributes as A
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (style, id)
```

## Update

Figured it out with help from comments. It was `node` vs `Svg.node`. When I changed it to `Svg.node` the problem went away. Question is:

1. Why did this fix it?
2. What is going on under the covers here that makes this important?
3. Can this be made typesafe so that the problem I experienced could be a compile time error?

Comment: Show us the code that generates the SVG. I imagine that's where the problem lies.

Comment: More than likely that the poster is trying to use elm-html for svg elements and getting confused when it doesn't work (there's an [elm-svg](https://github.com/evancz/elm-svg) library)

Comment: Updated with code @RobertLongson

Comment: @kakigoori updated with code, also I am using elm-svg and I don't think there is a difference.

Comment: It seems that `Svg.node` and `Html.node` have similar signatures:

`> Html.node
<function: node> : String -> List Html.Attribute -> List Html.Html -> Html.Html`

`> Svg.node
<function> : String -> List Svg.Attribute -> List Svg.Svg -> Svg.Svg
`

I checked `Svg.Svg` and `Html.Html` types and both are aliases of `Node`. Since you get different behaviours, for sure the implementations differ.

Comment: The aliasing to `Node` for both `Svg.Svg` and `Html.Html` and to `Property` for `Svg.Attribute` and `Html.Attribute` explain why you don't get compilation errors.

Answer (score 3):

Its cause of this 2 lines:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Svg
```

The first one imports all attributes of `Html` including `node` the second just import the `Svg` namespace. So when you are using `node` in this the environment `node` is the `Html.node`. You would get an compile error with this imports:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Svg exposing (..)
```

or  this:

```
import Html exposing (node)
import Svg exposing (node)
```

cause then, Elm did not know which `node` you want to use. 
So its safer to import the functions that you needed and not using `(..)`

So the main question is why does `Html.node` accepts `List Svg.Attribute` without throwing an error. Its cause [`Svg.Attribute`](https://github.com/evancz/elm-svg/blob/2.0.1/src/Svg.elm#L81) and [`Html.Attribute`](https://github.com/evancz/elm-html/blob/4.0.2/src/Html.elm#L78) are not real types but type aliases for `VirtualDom.Property`. So for the compiler both are the same type. Same for `Htm.Html` and `Svg.Svg` which are both aliases for `VirtualDom.Node`.

In the end both `node` functions have the Signature

```
String -> List VirtualDom.Property -> List VirtualDom.Node -> VirtualDom.Node
```

so the compiler cant distinguish between them.

Comment: Thank you! However, this doesn't answer any of my 3 questions.

Comment: Sorry but it answers all of them in my opinion. The problem is that you import all function when using `(..)`. So they are now available under the name with out the need of the namespace prefix. So `Html.node` and `node` are the same thing.

Comment: Do in the **update** section, I stated as much. I know that the manner of imports and mixing up `Svg.node` and `Html.node`. I get that, but WHY does this matter? What is different under the covers of the `Html` and `Svg` modules that makes this difference important? Why was this not a type error? Could it be a type error? Here are the questions as stated above:  

1. Why did this fix it?
2. What is going on under the covers here that makes this important?
3. Can this be made typesafe so that the problem I experienced could be a compile time error?

Comment: Your answer correctly asserts that `Svg.node` vs `Html.node` was the problem, but does nothing to explain why its the case.

Comment: add a sentence on why this not lead to an compile error

Comment: I did. Its in question 3.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I did. I add a sentence to my answer.

Comment: Again, you are telling me "what" but not "why". I'm sorry, but that's all I'm interested in, I already know the "what".

Comment: up1 for all the work you've done on this so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here is the code for both `node` functions:

```
--Html.node
node : String -> List Attribute -> List Html -> Html
node =
    VirtualDom.node


--Svg.node
node : String -> List Attribute -> List Svg -> Svg
node name =
  \attributes children ->
    VirtualDom.node name (svgNamespace :: attributes) children
```

Maybe the compiler should warn you when this happens.

Comment: The problem is that both functions have the same signature. `Html.Attribute` and `Svg.Attribute` are both aliases for `VirtualDom.Property`. Same for Svg.Svg and `Html.Html` which are just aliases for `VirtualDom.Node`.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I said that it might be good to get an warning from compiler.

Comment: Interesting, so the reason it fails has to do with the missing `svgNamespace`, but what is that? When I look at the rendered page the source looks no different.

Comment: it should have the namespace also:
    `svgNamespace : Attribute
    svgNamespace =
      VirtualDom.property "namespace" (Json.string     "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")`